# How to add data labels to dimple.js bar charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am trying to add data lables to each bar in the dimple bar chart. I want to add the same as shown in this example.http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_custom_styling. But I want to add the number on top of each bar in the chart. My code is as below. I am not sure how to capture the 'rect' shape and append a text to it.Please advise.

```
<div id="test" class="column">        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#test", 590, 335);            
        var data = [
            {"Month": "2014-01-10", "Color": "Yellow", "Percentage": 20},
            {"Month": "2014-02-10", "Color": "Yellow", "Percentage": 32},
            {"Month": "2014-03-10", "Color": "Yellow", "Percentage": 20},
            {"Month": "2014-04-10", "Color": "Yellow", "Percentage": 32},
            {"Month": "2014-01-10", "Color": "Red", "Percentage": 10},
            {"Month": "2014-02-10", "Color": "Red", "Percentage": 25},
            {"Month": "2014-03-10", "Color": "Red", "Percentage": 15},
            {"Month": "2014-04-10", "Color": "Red", "Percentage": 30}
            ];
        var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);            
        chart.setBounds(80, 30, 340, 200);
        var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Month", "Color"]);
        var y1 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Percentage");
        var bars = chart.addSeries("Color", dimple.plot.bar, [x, y1]);
        bars.barGap = 0.5;
        chart.addLegend(50, 10, 510, 20, "right");            
        chart.draw();
        svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", chart._xPixels() + chart._widthPixels() / 2)
                .attr("y", chart._yPixels() - 10)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .style("font-size", "75%")
                .text("Sample Text")
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the linked example which relates to bar labelling is this one:

```
// Set some custom display elements for each series shape
mySeries.afterDraw = function (s, d) {

    var shape = d3.select(s);

    // Add some bar labels for the yValue
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", parseFloat(shape.attr("x")) + shape.attr("width") / 2)
      .attr("y", parseFloat(shape.attr("y")) + (shape.attr("height") > 30 ? (shape.attr("height") / 2 + 8) : - 10))
      .style("font-family", "courier new")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "16px")
      .style("fill", "#ecf0f1")
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .text(yAxis._getFormat()(d.yValue));

  };
```

This has a check which puts the text at the top if the height of the rectangle is less than 30.  Therefore you just need to modify the y assignment to remove the condition:

```
.attr("y", parseFloat(shape.attr("y")) - 10)
```

This should put all labels at the top of their bars instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", chart._xPixels() + chart._widthPixels() / 2)
                .attr("y", chart._yPixels() - 10)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .style("font-size", "75%")
                .text("Sample Text")
```

In the above code `.attr("x", chart._xPixels() + chart._widthPixels() / 2)` is to keep text in Horizontal and `.attr("y", chart._yPixels() - 10)` is keep our text vertical, So if you need to keep text on the top of rect use the y attribute which you are using for rect and add some figure inorder to keep text on the rect.
Hope you can understand.If not ask for more.Okay